# Is there any possibility for kind of batch processing events in a webview?

Tags: java, android, android-webview

I'm trying to create an app, which automates interactions with the Internet. I'm using WebView to open certain websites and I want to batch process some predefined events like: click on that image, submit that web form etc. For that I need some sort of delay between them. I already tried to use "sleep", but that didn't work out. Whenever I try to call WebView methods in a thread, it obviously throws an exception stating that it's not allowed to call them in other threads than the main one. 
Is it somehow possible to achieve, what I was asking for?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Without trying to provide an answer either way as to the feasibility, it should be stated that sleep is a poor tool for sequencing actions. Either you wait too long (and things are slower than they can be) or too little (and the previous action hasn't completed). You should look for some way to detect that the previous event has completed (*or failed*) before doing the next thing, e.g. callbacks, promises etc.

Comment: Well, that sounds promising. I will look into it. Thank you, Andy.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the start command, for example

```
start "https://gogole.com
```